# How to Create an HTML Form That Sends You an Email on my ruby on rails app

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, email, html-email, sendmail

How can I send an email from my ruby on rails website
I dont want to store the data on my database. I just want to send email like this simple form

```
<form action="mailto:nourfiverr@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
 Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name"><br>
 E-mail:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail"><br>
Comment:<br>
<input type="text" name="comment" size="50"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

This form is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from your code, you are basically asking how to implement a simple contact form in Rails. You may want to checkout the gem `mail_form` here https://github.com/heartcombo/mail_form